# General Fixture Setup with PowerMockito and @BeforeClass

Tags: testing, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I have a test where I configure some general fixtures however after using PowerMockRule the static variables which I configure in my @BeforeClass method reset to null. This causes the following test to fail however if you remove PowerMockRule it passes.

```
public class Test
{
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private static String MyString;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() throws Exception
    {
        MyString = "FOO";
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        assertEquals("FOO", MyString);
    }
}
```

Comment: how you have solved your issue then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer, but you are not going to like it.

**Short answer**:it looks like a defect in PowerMock, so [create a issue](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/new) in our bug tracker

**Long answer**: As you may know the PowerMock to be able mock static, private and so on loads classes by custom class loader and modified byte code. Then `@PowerMockRunner`is used then PowerMock can control loading a test class and the test class is also loaded by custom class loader. In case if another jUnitRunner runs test and the `PowerMockRule`is used, then the test class and all other classes that is needed for test are loaded with standard class loader. PowerMock reloads all these classes either by using deep coping with serializing/deserializing or by using [objenesis](http://objenesis.org). So as class is reloaded all static fields which was initialised are `null`.

I've briefly checked code and I haven't found test for your cases and that we processed `@BeforeClass`, so [create a issue](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/new) in our bug tracker and I'll check it deeply.

By the way, please, also point which version do you use and which dependencies do you use.

Comment: Is it still not fixed, facing the same issue with the latest versions.